# Converting nested ArrayType of String to Nested ArrayType of date using UDF spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, multidimensional-array, nested, user-defined-functions

**Input**:

```
f1 : [["2017-08-08","2017/08/08"],["2017-08-08","2017/08/08"]]
```

schema for f1: `ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType))`

I want to convert date values from String to date format using spark UDF.
Here input may have `Array[Any]`. I had written udf which works for single dimensional value like `["2017-08-07","2013/08/02"]`. For single dimensional my udf will be:

```
def toDateFormatUdf(dateFormat:String) = udf(( dateValue: mutable.WrappedArray[_]) =>  dateValue match{
      case null => null
      case datevalue: mutable.WrappedArray[String] => datevalue.map(date => new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(String.valueOf(date)).getTime))
})
```

I have tried with `Seq[Row]` type as UDF parameter but unable to form the logic. Is there any way to implement UDF for the multidimensional array in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

If data had consistent format you could `cast`, but here it will exclude `yyyy/MM/dd` records:

```
val df = Seq((1L, Seq(Seq("2017-08-08", "2017/08/08"), Seq("2017-08-08","2017/08/08")))).toDF("id", "dates")

df.select($"dates".cast("array<array<date>>")).show(1, false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|dates                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(2017-08-08, null), WrappedArray(2017-08-08, null)]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here I'd only rewrite the format:

```
val f1 = "(^[0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$".r
val f2 = "(^[0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})$".r

val reformat = udf((xxs: Seq[Seq[String]]) => xxs match {
  case null => null
  case xxs => xxs.map {
    case null => null
    case xs => xs.map { x=> {
      x match {
        case null => null
        case f1(_, _, _) => x
        case f2(year, month, day) => s"${year}-${month}-${day}"
        case _ => null
      }
    }}
  }
})
```

and cast

```
df.select(reformat($"dates")).show(1, false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|UDF(dates)                                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(2017-08-08, 2017-08-08), WrappedArray(2017-08-08, 2017-08-08)]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

to avoid unnecessary initialization of the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Is it possible to make a generic UDF which will support any dimensional array of string inputs ?

Comment: I am not able to find solution for generic UDF. So is it a good idea to write different UDF for each dimension ? Something like for 1D array my udf parameter will be Seq[String],for 2D array it will be Seq[Seq[String]],like wise for 3D,4D...